# Save Geolocalization

Tags: android, firebase

I have a problem in my Android app. I have a service for geolocalization and I need to save the position on my DB.

When the app is running in the foreground I can to save the position, but when the app is running in the background the information isn't saved.

I used Firebase with Android.

Thanks.

Comment: Android app processes are killed after some time when they are not visible on screen, unless you do something to prevent that.

Comment: But in the service, when is it close to the end position, send a notification, this working fine, but  not save on firebase database

Answer (score 2):

With Android 10 for accessing location in background you need special permisson, or you can do it with a foreground service.